# Error VrPanoramaView Xml

Tags: android, google-vr

I am using the new library for vr360 image from Google

I have an issue when i run the app on Samsung Galaxy s6 (6.0) it crash. But when i run the app on other devices etc Nexus 4 (5.+) all running good.

I try to run the Lab app on S6 and works perfect.. 
Demo Url: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/vr_view_app_101/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0

My error:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.pano.VrPanoramaView
```

My Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.pano.VrPanoramaView
        android:id="@+id/pano_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My Gradle :

```
   compile project(':gvr-android-sdk/libraries:common')
    compile project(':gvr-android-sdk/libraries:commonwidget')
    compile project(':gvr-android-sdk/libraries:panowidget')
```

and Settings.gradle

```
include ':gvr-android-sdk/libraries:audio'
include ':gvr-android-sdk/libraries:base'
include ':gvr-android-sdk/libraries:common'
include ':gvr-android-sdk/libraries:commonwidget'
include ':gvr-android-sdk/libraries:panowidget'
include ':gvr-android-sdk/libraries:videowidget'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following abiFilters to buildTypes in build.gradle file of your project.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }}
```

Comment: This will work for most of the devices except Asus zenfone series and some other devices. To support all the devices you need to have different builds for different architectures. Check out the docs here https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-android-sdk/tree/master/libraries/native

Answer (score -1):

Replace this: compile project(':gvr-android-sdk/libraries:panowidget')

to this: compile project(':gvr-android-sdk/libraries:videowidget')